# why is my code not printing the largest number?

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
void isMax(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

    int ans1, ans0, x;


    a = !b, a = !c, a = !d,
        b = !c, b = !d,
        c = !d, c = !a;

        if (a<b && b>c) { // ans0 starts 

            if (b > d) {

                std::cout << b << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << d << std::endl;
            }
        }

        else if (a < b && b < c) {

            if (c > d) {
                std::cout << c << std::endl;
            }

            else {
                std::cout << d << std::endl;
            }
        }
        //ans1

        else if (a > b&& a > c) {
            if (a > c&& a > d) {
                std::cout << a << std::endl;
            }
            else if (a > c&& a < d) {

                std::cout << d << std::endl;
            }

            else if (a<c && c>d) {

                std::cout << c << std::endl;
            }
            else if (a < c && c < d) {
                std::cout << d << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "invalid numbers ahead." << std::endl;
            }

        }

        std::cout << a << b << c << d << std::endl;

};


int main() {

    isMax(3, 4, 6, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

it kind of worked before i added

```
a = !b, a = !c, a = !d,
       b = !c, b = !d,
       c = !d, c = !a;
```

this part but did not work when i give the same values for a,b,c,d that`s why i added that part and now it does not work at all.

What is my mistake here ?

This image shows what i am trying to turn into code. Basically i`m trying to write a function that prints out the largest of four variables.

[image: 1]

Comment: What is the point of the `a = !b` (etc)? You are changing the values here. Also, your code does not match the logic of the image...

Comment: what do you execpt the `a = !b ....` part to do? You added it why?

Comment: `a = ...` followed by `a = ...` followed by `a = ...`. What is the value of `a`? Which assignment will be the final result?

Comment: First rule of compound comparisons: always keep the arrows in the same direction.   So `a<b && b>c` become `a<b && c<b`.  It makes it much easier to read.

Comment: What the others said, plus: As your graph already shows, this gets quite complicated very fast. It would be easier to compare the first two values, store the greater value of those, then compare this with the third value etc.

Comment: If you only have a limited number of values, use [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max). If you have a larger amount of values then put them in a container and use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: This has to be the most complicated implementation of max that i have ever seen.

Comment: What the...?  Why not simply `std::cout << std::max(std::max(std::max(a, b), c), d);`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Considering that `std::max` support initializer lists, perhaps `std::max({a, b, c, d})` even?

Comment: I wrote an answer, though seeing how this slowly evolves into a "how to get the maximum of four numbers without using the obvious solution"-challenge I'd rather vote to close it as typo

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -- Yes, the initializer list works also.

Comment: i meant =! to show a and b are not the same boy i was wrong. thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your schema, it should be:

```
void DisplayMax(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (b < a) {
        if (c < a) {
            if (d < a) {
                std::cout << a;
            } else { // a <= d
                std::cout << d;
            }
        } else { // b < a <= c
            if (c < d) {
                std::cout << d;
            } else {
                std::cout << c;
            }
        }
    } else { // a <= b
        if (c < b) {
            if (d < b) {
                std::cout << b;
            } else { // b <= d
                std::cout << d;
            }
        } else { // a <= b <= c
            if (c < d) {
                std::cout << d;
            } else {
                std::cout << c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, as shown in other answer, there is simpler ways.

or with std:

```
void DisplayMax(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

    std::cout << std::max({a, b, c, d});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`a != b;` is true when `a` and `b` are different. What you wrote is `a = !b;` which is "assign to a the logically negated value of b".

I do not see how such assignment could make any sense here. That's why you get correct results without it and non-sense results when you add that assignments.

PS: Even if you "fix" it by writing `a != b;` the statement alone will have no effect. I suppose you want to return early or skip some of the later conditions when some input is equal.

Answer (score 0):

This code is over complicated for something fairly simple. If you're new to programming, I suggest you try using arrays, in that way you can easily decide which number is max.

For example:

```
void isMax(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int j[4] = { a,b,c,d };
    int max = j[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (j[i] > max){ max = j[i]; }
    }
    cout << max;
}
```

This is a better way to do it.

Comment: you can start the loop at `i=1` because on the first iteration you compare the first element with itself

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues:

- Your logic seem over complicated for printing the largest of 4 variables.
- The name of the isMax function doesn't reflect what it does.
- I don't understand the need for a "invalid numbers ahead" if indeed printing the largest of four integers is intended.

I propose a simpler logic with fewer conditions but another variable on the heap.

```
#include <iostream>
int largestOf(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

  int max = a;
  if (b > max) 
    max = b;
  if (c > max) 
    max = c;
  if (d > max) 
    max = d;

  return max;
}

void isMax(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  std::cout << largestOf(a, b, c, d) << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: the name of your `isMax` also does not reflect what it does ;)

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear at all what you expect the `a = !b, ...` to accomplish, so I'm going to ignore that.
I am also going to ignore the existence of `std::max` since this is clearly an exercise.

Your logic tree makes sense, but you can find a more convenient solution if you bark up a different but similar tree.

Consider the case when `a > b`, i.e. you know for certain that `b` is not the maximum.
Instead of continuing with `a`, now look at only `c` and `d`.
If `c > d`, you know that the maximum is not `d`, so it must be either `a` or `c`.
Likewise, if `d > c`, the maximum is either `a` or `d`.

The same line of reasoning for the case when `b > a` leads to the following algorithm:

1. Determine `max(a,b)`.
2. Determine `max(c,d)`.
3. The maximum of all four numbers is the maximum of the previous two results.

In code:

```
void isMax(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int ans0 = a > b ? a : b;
    int ans1 = c > d ? c : d;
    std::cout << (ans0 > ans1 ? ans0 : ans1) << std::endl;
}
```

On a side note, a function whose name begins with "is" usually returns a boolean, and you will find more use for a function that returns the maximum than you will of one that prints it.
You can always print that value later if you want to look at it.

Like this:

```
int max(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int ans0 = a > b ? a : b;
    int ans1 = c > d ? c : d;
    return ans0 > ans1 ? ans0 : ans1;
}
```